# Is there some quantitative measurement or concept that can distinguish between a photon and a gluon?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, experimental-physics, standard-model, gluons

Considering both photons and gluons have a mass of 0, a charge of 0, and a spin of 1, what distinguishes them? I want to exclude answers such as 'they influence different forces (i.e. photons are associated with electromagnetism and gluons govern the strong force)'. While this should be considered a reasonable answer, I am just interested as to whether there is some quantitative measure of this. 
If there isn't officially, is there a possibility of there being one, via analysing how they interact differently?

Comment: Why do you say that gluons are uncharged?

Answer (score 2):

What distinguishes photons and gluons qualitatively is what other fields they interact with, or “couple to”, and what distinguishes them quantitatively is the precise details of those interactions.

Photons interact with any fields that have nonzero electric charge (such as electrons and quarks). Gluons interact with any fields that have nonzero “color charge” (such as quarks and gluons).

The fact that there are direct interactions between gluons (because of their color charge) but no direct interactions between photons is a huge qualitative difference that leads to QCD being very different from QED, both at small distances (“asymptotic freedom”) and at large distances (“color confinement”).

The quantitative details of the interactions of these gauge bosons are given by the Feynman rules for the vertices involving them. The math for these is covered in books on quantum field theory. You can see these vertices in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#/media/File:Standard_Model_Feynman_Diagram_Vertices.png) in diagrams 2, 3, 6, and 9.

Despite both having the same mass, electric charge, and spin, and both being gauge bosons, photons and gluons are in no way indistinguishable. All you have to do to make this obvious is include color charge in your list of properties: gluons have color charge, while photons don’t.